# Software to make sure bookings are fulfilled and not just abandoned

Tags: mobile, booking

Think probably easiest to explain what I need it for and the kind of solution I envisaged, and if there's a better way to do it I'll be interested in that too.

I'm part of a tennis club, we have introduced new rules to minimise the spread of covid. You have to book to play in advance. We charge a yearly membership, and don't want to move to a pay-per-booking model (we have very few costs, thousands of pounds in the bank and some low-income members who would probably be upset about it and stop playing).

The problem is that people book to play but then don't turn up. We've restricted bookings to one or two a week by a member but it keeps happening. The bookings are anonymous except to the Skedda administrator, who obviously can't hang around the courts all day and write down whoever didn't turn up.

There is no WiFi on site (though there is power), but I thought of a possible solution, and wondered if it has ever been implemented. On the court, a screen which displays an arbitrary sequence of numbers, which changes every hour, taken from a simple text file which lists the time and date next to said number. This number could be represented by a qr code.

On the user side, the user has a smartphone app which scans the qr code, and checks the number against the date and time on the server, and records that the booking was actually used.

Does this absurdly specific thing exist?

Comment: Why not just have an app with a geofence (no pun intended) around the courts to confirm that the user is present. This requires that they bring their smartphone with them, but for most people that's not an issue. This doesn't require power or WiFi at the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an idea. I don't know if it is possible as I don't have experience.

When the user on side, he opens the app and it allows user to confirm location.

I can see in this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286152/get-current-location-during-app-launch ), they are doing it during launch but I guess you can have a `confirm at court` button.

And also ask the user to do it twice once when they start and when they finish to minimise the abuse.

I also assume current location does not need to be accurate because if user is nearby, they can still abuse any solution by checking in and then leaving.

Comment: Reasonable suggestion, although I don't think this is deliberate abuse so don't need people to check in twice